# How can I use JSONObject as in & out for a Jersey REST service W/ NATURAL notation?

Tags: rest, jersey

OK, I have a Jersey REST service and I want to use JSONObject as input and output. Method is POST. Problem is that the use of Pojos is not appropriate in this case, so I would rather avoid the overhead. NATURAL notation is important. The whole point is that I want a system that is very tolerant and will essentially accept any legitimate JSON. I also need the original form of the JSON preserved.

1. Possible?
2. How?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing forces you to take a POJO as your POST argument.  It can be a String in which case it will be a JSON string that you can easily map to and from a JSONObject.

```
@POST
public void post_something( String json ) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject( json );
    LOG.info( "Posting: {}", props.get( "name" );
}
```

Then you can just send "{\"name\":"\William Burroughs\"}" to your post request. You can also go from a map to a JSON string just as easily. For example:

```
   @GET
   public String get_something() {
       JSONObject object = myservice.getJSONOBject();
       return object.toString();
   }
```

Comment: The idea is to use JSONObject as my post argument and return value.

Comment: So what happens when you do that? I don't see why that should be any different. Maybe you don't have jettison configured properly?

Comment: What happens is the JSON is changed when it should not be.  The default should be the same as it was sent but Jersey/Jettison uses MAPPED instead of NATURAL:
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html#d4e949